# How to disable input method in C++ console?

Tags: c++, console-application

I'm making a text-based console game.

The Chinese input method is annoying as it blocks normal key input.

I tried to send NULL to ImmAssociateContext but it doesn't work.

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include <imm.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include<handleapi.h>
#include<iostream>
#pragma comment ( lib,"imm32.lib" )  
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SetConsoleTitle(TEXT("test"));
    char ch;

    ImmAssociateContext(FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("test")), NULL);
    cin >> ch;
    cout << ch;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Edit:
I don't need to input Chinese in this game.

About Chinese input:
When you input a letter in console, Chinese input methods would receive the input as pinyin, and turn it into Chinese characters.

(In the screenshot, aabbcc with dashline below is pinyin)

The same thing happened to Japanese input method.

This is not what I need. All I want is, when I press A, the console receives A.

About the code:

I'm using PDCurses in my project to draw a text-based gui and get key inputs.

Everything looks fine when the input method is turned off.

The code above shows ImmAssociateContext (google says it can turn off input method) doesn't work to me.

Comment: [Tag:winapi]?. .

Comment: Why are you using `FindWindow` instead of `GetConsoleWindow`?  Note that using `cin` to read single characters will still suffer from default buffering.  Look into `_kbhit()` and `_getch()` for Windows console keyboard input.

Comment: _getch() is still blocked by chinese input.

Comment: That only works with 8-bit characters, not UTF-8 or whatever encoding you're using. You need something that works with "wide" characters on Windows.

Comment: Are you using windows's built-in input method? Is it a possible option to ask the user to manually change the input method?

Comment: Note: Within games you're not really concerned about characters so much as *keypresses*, so you should hook into the event stream and decode keys directly. This allows you to pick up on non-character keys like shift and alt.